# Upstart script needs to run after /tmp is mounted and writable

Tags: linux, upstart

I have an Ubuntu Linux server that is running in a Vagrant virtual environment. I use the server for development of a web service. When the server starts up I have a shell script that needs to run once in order to setup a cache directory structure on the `/tmp/` filesystem.

```
description "setup web cache"

start on startup

script
    mkdir -p /tmp/cache/persistent
    mkdir -p /tmp/cache/models
    mkdir -p /tmp/cache/views
    chmod -R 777 /tmp/cache/
end script
```

When I boot the server I get an error message that show up in `/var/log/upstart/webcache.log`:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory `/tmp/cache': Read-only file system
```

Apparently `startup` is too soon to `start on`. The question is, when is `/tmp` available for writing and what do I pass to `start on`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your job needs to start when local file system is mounted most likely you need following definition: `start on local-filesystems`

See local-filesystem event [example](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man7/local-filesystems.7.html).

You will find overview of well known Upstart events [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man7/upstart-events.7.html).

Further on, your job is a short lived job and not a service/daemon. It will be more appropriate to use [task](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#task) stanza. In such way you might run a job that depends on cache directories created once those directories are actually created. Otherwise, if you define all dependent jobs to start runlevel [2345] dependent job might start before needed directories are created e.g. dependent job might use following definition: `start on started webcache`.

```
description "setup web cache"

start on  local-filesystems

task

script
    mkdir -p /tmp/cache/persistent
    mkdir -p /tmp/cache/models
    mkdir -p /tmp/cache/views
    chmod -R 777 /tmp/cache/
end script
```

Finally, you might consider using Vagrant [shell provisioner](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) to create needed cache directories.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I did consider shell provisioner, but provisioning only runs once, by default (though it can be forced to run each time), which is why I was looking for a way to put the functionality into the vagrant guest.

Comment: I don't know requirements but usual [location](http://www.linfo.org/var.html) for application cache would be /var/cache/app-name. However, in that case it will be on the application e.g. you to clean up cache. :)

Comment: That is good to know (though perhaps off topic). In this particular instance, the application is a web app, and as such is being run as the web user. The web user does not seem to have write access to `/var/cache` by default.

Comment: That is true. However, user www-data does not need write access to /var/cache but to /var/cache/app-name which could be granted during setup: `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/cache/app-name && chmod -R u+w /var/cache/app-name`. Speaking of been slightly off the topic: Whenever I found myself in a similar situation stepping back and asking myself which problem I am trying to solve and looking for alternatives turned out to be a good decision. In this case created directory structure will not persist since /tmp will be cleared on reboot. Instead of seeking for workaround redefine the problem. :)

Comment: I agree. Though in this case I do not mind the data being cleared on reboot since it is for development only. Though using `/var/cache/app` I could change the script to clear it for me instead of recreating it. Both are viable solutions for my current situation. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Though the accepted answer by @schkovich is certainly sufficient, I wanted to add that Vagrant emits a `vagrant-mounted` event. This event is emitted even after `local-filesystems`. I just had a situation in which I got the same error as described in the question, which could only be solved by:

```
start on vagrant-mounted
```

Source: [this](http://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount/) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

While reading through the "[Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practises](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#normal-start)" I found a section about "Normal start" which uses [runlevels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runlevel) for triggering an upstart script. Adjusting my script as follows allowed the script to run after `/tmp/` was mounted:

```
start on runlevel [2345]
```

There may well be other solutions that are equally viable.